# Se puede crear una función Powershell de tipo TimerTrigger de functionapp que se conecte a mi cuenta de azure?

Tags: powershell, azure

tengo mi función:

```
# Autenticar con Azure si no se ha iniciado sesión
if (-not (Get-AzContext)) {
    # Puedes proporcionar credenciales o utilizar otros métodos de autenticación aquí
    # Ten en cuenta que almacenar credenciales en el código puede no ser seguro en todos los casos.
    # Aquí un ejemplo simple usando el ID de aplicación y el secreto del cliente (no recomendado para producción sin medidas adicionales):
    $appId = "XXXXXXXXX@XXXXXX.XXX"
    $appSecret = "XXXXXXXXXX"
    $tenantId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    
    $secureAppSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString $appSecret -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object PSCredential($appId, $secureAppSecret)
    
    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -Tenant $tenantId
}

# Obtener el listado de suscripciones
$subcriptionsList = Get-AzSubscription | Select-Object Id, Name, TenantId, State

# Get the current universal time in the default string format.
$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

# The 'IsPastDue' property is 'true' when the current function invocation is later than scheduled.
if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
}

# Write an information log with the current time.
Write-Host "Salida: $currentUTCtime"

# Devolver el listado de suscripciones como salida de la función
$subcriptionsList
```

La cual, en mi local, devuelve las suscripciones correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, cuando la ejecuto en mi función de tipo TimerTrigger, me sale este error:

```
ERROR: ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'XXXXXX' was not found in the directory 'XXXXXX'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Trace ID: dea215e0-952a-4716-80a3-0759c0572c00 Correlation ID: 41ef2fdc-7b6e-46ae-a8c9-11af7e615ec8 Timestamp: 2024-01-19 17:06:00Z Exception : Type : Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException TargetSite : Name : FailWrapAndThrow DeclaringType : Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope, Azure.Identity, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXX MemberType : Method Module : Azure.Identity.dll Message : ClientSecretCredential authentication failed: AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'XXXXXXXXX' was not found in the directory 'XXXXXXXX'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Trace ID: dea215e0-952a-4716-80a3-0759c0572c00 Correlation ID: 41ef2fdc-7b6e-46ae-a8c9-11af7e615ec8 Timestamp: 2024-01-19 17:06:00Z InnerException : Type : Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException StatusCode : 400 ResponseBody : {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'XXXXXXX' was not found in the directory 'XXXXXXXXX'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Trace ID: dea215e0-952a-4716-80a3-0759c0572c00 Correlation ID: 41ef2fdc-7b6e-46ae-a8c9-11af7e615ec8 Timestamp: 2024-01-19 17:06:00Z","error_codes":[700016],"timestamp":"2024-01-19 17:06:00Z","trace_id":"dea215e0-952a-4716-80a3-0759c0572c00","correlation_id":"41ef2fdc-7b6e-46ae-a8c9-11af7e615ec8","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700016"} Headers : Key : Cache-Control Value : Length : 18 Key : Pragma Value : Length : 8 Key : Strict-Transport-Security Value : Length : 35 Key : X-Content-Type-Options Value : Length : 7 Key : P3P Value : Length : 34 Key : client-request-id Value : Length : 36 Key : x-ms-request-id Value : Length : 36 Key : x-ms-ests-server Value : Length : 29 Key : x-ms-clitelem Value : Length : 12 Key : x-ms-httpver Value : Length : 3 Key : X-XSS-Protection Value : Length : 1 Key : Set-Cookie Value : Length : 128 Length : 66 Length : 64 Key : Date Value : Length : 29 CorrelationId : 41ef2fdc-7b6e-46ae-a8c9-11af7e615ec8 ErrorCode : unauthorized_client TargetSite : Name : MoveNext DeclaringType : Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase+<HandleTokenRefreshErrorAsync>d__26, Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.39.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a613f4dd989e8ae MemberType : Method Module : Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll Message : AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'XXXXXXXX' was not found in the directory 'XXXXXXX'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Trace ID: dea215e0-952a-4716-80a3-0759c0572c00 Correlation ID: 41ef2fdc-7b6e-46ae-a8c9-11af7e615ec8 Timestamp: 2024-01-19 17:06:00Z Source : Microsoft.Identity.Client HResult : -2146233088 StackTrace : at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.HandleTokenRefreshErrorAsync(MsalServiceException e, MsalAccessTokenCacheItem cachedAccessTokenItem) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenForClientParameters clientParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Identity.AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilderExtensions.ExecuteAsync[T](AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder`1 builder, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Identity.MsalConfidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClientCoreAsync(String[] scopes, String tenantId, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Identity.MsalConfidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(String[] scopes, String tenantId, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) Source : Azure.Identity HResult : -2146233088 StackTrace : at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage) at Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Authenticators.MsalAccessToken.GetAccessTokenAsync(String callerClassName, String parametersLog, TokenCredential tokenCredential, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String tenantId, String userId, String homeAccountId) at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Factories.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate(IAzureAccount account, IAzureEnvironment environment, String tenant, SecureString password, String promptBehavior, Action`1 promptAction, IAzureTokenCache tokenCache, String resourceId) at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient.Login(IAzureAccount account, IAzureEnvironment environment, String tenantId, String subscriptionId, String subscriptionName, SecureString password, Boolean skipValidation, Action`1 promptAction, String name, Boolean shouldPopulateContextList, Int32 maxContextPopulation, String authScope) at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.<>c__DisplayClass127_2.<ExecuteCmdlet>b__5() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread) --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.<>c__DisplayClass127_0.<ExecuteCmdlet>b__1(AzureRmProfile localProfile, RMProfileClient profileClient, String name) at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.<>c__DisplayClass136_0.<SetContextWithOverwritePrompt>b__0(AzureRmProfile prof, RMProfileClient client) at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Common.AzureContextModificationCmdlet.ModifyContext(Action`2 contextAction) at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.SetContextWithOverwritePrompt(Action`3 setContextAction) at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.ExecuteCmdlet() at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.<>c__3`1.<ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob>b__3_0(T c) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet, Action`1 executor) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord() CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], AuthenticationFailedException FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand InvocationInfo : MyCommand : Connect-AzAccount ScriptLineNumber : 17 OffsetInLine : 5 HistoryId : 1 ScriptName : C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2\run.ps1 Line : Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -Tenant $tenantId PositionMessage : At C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2\run.ps1:17 char:5 + Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -Tena … + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ PSScriptRoot : C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2 PSCommandPath : C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2\run.ps1 InvocationName : Connect-AzAccount CommandOrigin : Internal ScriptStackTrace : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2\run.ps1: line 17 PipelineIterationInfo :
Error
2024-01-19 17:06:00.356
Error
2024-01-19 17:06:00.356
ERROR: Run Connect-AzAccount to login. Exception : Type : System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException ErrorRecord : Exception : Type : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException Message : Run Connect-AzAccount to login. HResult : -2146233087 CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation TargetSite : Name : get_DefaultContext DeclaringType : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.AzureRMCmdlet MemberType : Method Module : Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager.dll Message : Run Connect-AzAccount to login. Source : Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager HResult : -2146233079 StackTrace : at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.AzureRMCmdlet.get_DefaultContext() at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.GetAzureRMSubscriptionCommand.BeginProcessing() at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing() at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin() CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-AzSubscription], PSInvalidOperationException FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.GetAzureRMSubscriptionCommand InvocationInfo : MyCommand : Get-AzSubscription ScriptLineNumber : 21 OffsetInLine : 21 HistoryId : 1 ScriptName : C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2\run.ps1 Line : $subcriptionsList = Get-AzSubscription | Select-Object Id, Name, TenantId, State PositionMessage : At C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2\run.ps1:21 char:21 + $subcriptionsList = Get-AzSubscription | Select-Object Id, Name, Tena … + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ PSScriptRoot : C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2 PSCommandPath : C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2\run.ps1 InvocationName : Get-AzSubscription CommandOrigin : Internal ScriptStackTrace : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger2\run.ps1: line 21
```

Me podrían ayudar?